# How to define a Protocol with generic function and some View as return type

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create a protocol with one function for the following

```
@ViewBuilder
func navigate<T: View>(content: () -> T) -> some View {
    switch self{
    case .list:
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")){ content() }
    default:
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

This is my try and it doesn't work

```
protocol Test {
    associatedtype Result: View

    func navigate<T: View>(content: () -> T) -> Result
}
```

Comment: Protocol says that you will adhere to certain rules. In this case you're saying that I<Any> will have the navigate method defined so that you can call it on me<Any>. In other words every View you want to adhere to that protocol would have to have that method in it<The View>'s own definition file. 
If that's your intention then you can you just declare whatever <Any> you're working with claims conformance to Test.

Comment: Got it, then how can I force children to implement navigate function?

Comment: Actually nav link is a struct without inheritance, so I'm not real sure the best way to handle that. You could make an extension and return an optional nav link.?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explicitly disallowed by the [Associated Type Inference](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md#associated-type-inference) section of the Opaque Result Types proposal. From the proposal:

> Associated type inference can only infer an opaque result type for a non-generic requirement, because the opaque type is parameterized by the function's own generic arguments. For instance, in:
>
> ```
> protocol P {
>  associatedtype A: P
>  func foo<T: P>(x: T) -> A
> }
>
> struct Foo: P {
>  func foo<T: P>(x: T) -> some P {
>    return x
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> there is no single underlying type to infer A to, because the return type of foo is allowed to change with T.

To make this more specific to your question, in order to conform to `Test`, there must be exactly one type that can be assigned to `Result`. However, your return type is generic, so it depends on the what is passed. The actual (non-opaque) return type of `navigate` is:

```
_ConditionalContent<NavigationLink<T, Text>, EmptyView>
```

But `T` is a type parameter and changes depending on how `navigate` is called. So there is no one type that can be assigned to `Result`.

You'll need something that can return a single, non-parameterized type. For the example you've given, that's probably AnyView, which is annoying.

That said, what you've written here doesn't really feel like a protocol. It looks a lot like just a function. I'd think a lot about how many different ways `navigate` could be written. If everyone would implement it the same way, that's just a function. (If you give another example of a conforming type, it might help to design a better approach.)

Comment: Holy crap. What are you a rocket surgeon? I don't know what you just said, but it sounds right. Very well articulated. You get an upvote from me.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, it was very helpful. I was thinking about abstracting the navigation from SwiftUI Views so I wanted to create enum with navigate function for each module.

Comment: I generally don't recommend an enum for such things. An enum suggests there is a fixed set of reasonable values. When there could really be an arbitrarily long list of values that could grow over time, that's really a struct (and may be a single struct type with many static instances). I'd have to see how you were trying to call this, though, to know how to implement that best.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this where you call it on the destination.

```
extension View {
     func navigate< Destination: View, Label: View>(content: Label) -> some View   {
          NavigationLink(destination: Destination) { content.    }
     }
}
```

The problem is you can't find out the caller inside the method because you're extending a protocol.